# Why browser displaying blank page when javascript turned off

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have build a website using MVC4, jQuery UI, Twitter Bootstrap etc using that template http://bit.ly/1aAcIJq

But the thing is, when Javascript is turned off the browser does not displaying anything, just blank page, however if I click view source so I can see the complete page source.

If you disable javascript and load http://bit.ly/1aAcIJq you will see what I mean

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Remove the `visibility:hidden` from your CSS and your all set to go.

Comment: Well.. I removed it from the body I think and it showed the website.

Comment: @putvande got it. Unbelievable, my next question will be: what shall i do with it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, I found the problem. You have to change `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visible` or just get rid of it.  You will not have any of the flashy features and some of the functionality because JavaScript has been disabled, but it will display the website.

Comment: Did you find that out all by yourself?

Comment: Honestly, yes.  I just now saw your comment because I was looking through the code and hadn't refreshed the page.  I was using `Inspect Element` on Chrome and looked at each element and saw the CSS styling for `<div id="over">...</div>`.

Comment: Hehe, no worries :-).

Comment: I did notice that some things do not display correctly because JS is turned off.  The majority of users will have it enabled so you shouldn't have too much of a problem.  The only fix is to restyle the elements and add some JS to account for the changes.

Comment: NoJS version looking like a hell. Anyway I might think of having somekind of noscript version later...

Comment: It will look like that because it uses JS to style the page.  This is why I usually don't go too crazy with JS styling.